# How can I avoid highlighting empty cells when formatting date ranges?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I need to highlight past due items, but Google sheets is also highlighting all of the blank cells in that respective column, which I don't want. (Is it because Google sheets is assigning blank cells a value of zero?) Anyway, my custom formula is as such:

=$A1:$A<=today()

I've tried various combinations of formulas similar to this one:

=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($A1:$A),$A1:$A<=today())

but my syntax is off somewhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `=and($A1<=today(),$A<>"")`

Answer (score 0):

your formula is just a bit spotty at one of the closing brackets.

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($A1:$A)),$A1:$A<=today())
```

OR

```
=(A:A<=today())*(A:A<>"")
```